# External table is not in the expected format. MS office not installed. Creating xlsx file using C#

Tags: c#, installation, oledb

Trying to create excel file from C#.

Challenges

**The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.**
Resolved using [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5c04c7-157f-4955-a14b-41d912d50a64/how-to-fix-error-the-microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine)

Now stuck on

An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

**Additional information: External table is not in the expected format.**

Searching a lot since my morning. No results yet.

OS- 64 bit, MS Office not installed, AccessDb file given in path above is installed.
Can I create Oledb connection without having MS Office?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of hit and try I finally found a wall where I was hitting my head.
**External table is not in the expected format.**
This error not only means that you have some problem with driver. It can also means you file format is unrecognised.

This was because, I was creating xlsx file programatically.

```
    string pathWithExtension=location + fileName+DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddss") + ".xls";

               if (!File.Exists(pathWithExtension))
               {
                   File.Create(pathWithExtension).Close(); //Dont create this file. Won't create valid xlsx file
                   //pathWithExtension = "C:/myFile.xlsx"; try using some template like this
                   ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathWithExtension + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES'";
                   //call con.Open() throws above exception saying "External file is...."
```

> This was because when I was creating xlsx file manually, it was not an
>   actual xlsx file. It was just a simple txt file with only give
>   extension as xlsx